# If there is a suspicion a person has accepted their own answer posted from another account, can anything be done about it?

Tags: discussion

I believe I have encountered posts by a person who uses two accounts, say $x$ and $y$. If that is indeed the case, they have used $x$ to answer a question posted from $y$ and then made $y$ accept $x$'s answer. Is there anything that can be done about this including finding out whether my suspicion is correct)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your best option is to flag it (the question/answer) for mod attention (and give enough details), and they will take care of it.

Comment: I've just realized that what I had in mind was an awarded bounty. I think it was. I got completely confused by a number of oddities coming up when I was trying to figure out what was going on. I think I'm not going to flag anything because I think it may be some kind of legitimate software feature I have no idea about that was used by someone or many someones.

Comment: OK, I may be going paranoid, but I'm flagging this. Something's not right...

Comment: Mandatory joke: ymar = Aryabhata :)